# java spring starter question

Tags: java, spring

I am looking into Spring and I want to ask the following:
I see that there is Spring2 and Spring3.
My question is, should I ignore Spring2, or If I read on Spring2 the concepts are the same in Spring3?
I ask this, because when starting to look into EJB2 I found out that it is obsolete (replaced completely by EJB3) and I wasted my time.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider them to be the same. EJB2 to EJB3 was an incredible step forward. Spring 3 is more functionality and tons of marketing.

Comment: So if I read on Spring2 (from book etc) I will have no problem, right?

Comment: Reading a book on Spring2 will be very valuable to understand the whole IOC, decoupled OO design and testability thing. Generally it's very good. Having said that though, why don't you just go with Spring3?

Comment: For practical reasons.I already happen to have book on Sping2 in my library available and was afraid not to waste time on these. But if the 2 releases are the same then great

Comment: It's definitelly not a waste of time. Go ahead and read it. That's what I did 4 years ago and now I just wrote a Spring3 (my first app - with spring mvc and hibernate) application without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

EJB and Spring have nothing to do with one another. Versions numbers are just numbers.

Spring 3 is an incremental imporvement on Spring 2, and works in much the same way.

EJB3 was a complete redesign of EJB 2 (and, clearly, is "inspired by" Spring).

Answer (score 2):

Information about Spring2 will apply to Spring3, but some portion will be replaced with changed and/or new functionality.

Knowledge about EJB2 is not obsolete, there still exist EJB2 implementations that will need developers to maintain them.  Learning EJB3 seems (to me anyway) like the way to go vs learning EJB2.

For Spring3, there is a reasonable reference document [available online here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).